# Determining what # is being dialed on Android

Tags: android, android-emulator

I know that with the telephony manager listen, you can listen for 3 different states.  Iknow that CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK indicates that there is at least one call that is dialing, active, etc.  My question is- with the telephony manager, is there a way to determine what number the phone is off hook with?  I thought getLine1Number() might return that phone number that is being dialed, but it is not what I expect.  I am working with 2 emulators, and added a log line so that I could see what that method is doing.  When dialing another emulator, I expected getLine1Number() to return 5554, but it was 15555218135.  Perhaps there is another method I should be using instead?  Do I need to be into the source code to get the information I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly, getLine1Number() is returning the phone's number.  I currently have a work around of having the user use the program to initiate a call.  They enter the number to dial in a text box and that way I can capture the number.